# IDE Fatal Errors: getChildren failed for ActionGroup

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, stack-trace, fatal-error

When I am opening a project with Android Studio IDE, I am getting Android Studio IDE Fatal Error.
How can I resolve this issue?

**Stacktrace:**

```
getChildren failed for ActionGroup(com.android.tools.idea.testartifacts.instrumented.testsuite.actions.ImportTestGroup, id=ImportTests) with text=Test History

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException: PersistentEnumerator storage corrupted C:\Users\hissain.sk\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.3\caches\names.dat
    at com.intellij.util.ExceptionUtil.rethrow(ExceptionUtil.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSConnection.handleError(PersistentFSConnection.java:299)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.handleError(FSRecords.java:723)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.readAndHandleErrors(FSRecords.java:255)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.getNameId(FSRecords.java:509)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.findExistingChildInfo(PersistentFSImpl.java:439)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.lambda$findChildInfo$4(PersistentFSImpl.java:390)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.update(FSRecords.java:306)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.findChildInfo(PersistentFSImpl.java:427)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.findInPersistence(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.doFindChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.findChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:78)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.findChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:537)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.findChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFile.findFileByRelativePath(VirtualFile.java:382)
    at com.android.tools.idea.testartifacts.instrumented.testsuite.actions.ImportUtpResultActionKt$findFileByRelativePathToContentRoot$1$1.invoke(ImportUtpResultAction.kt:268)
    at com.android.tools.idea.testartifacts.instrumented.testsuite.actions.ImportUtpResultActionKt$findFileByRelativePathToContentRoot$1$1.invoke(ImportUtpResultAction.kt:267)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:210)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:170)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:194)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.firstOrNull(_Sequences.kt:168)
    at com.android.tools.idea.testartifacts.instrumented.testsuite.actions.ImportUtpResultActionKt$findFileByRelativePathToContentRoot$1.invoke(ImportUtpResultAction.kt:269)
    at com.android.tools.idea.testartifacts.instrumented.testsuite.actions.ImportUtpResultActionKt$findFileByRelativePathToContentRoot$1.invoke(ImportUtpResultAction.kt:266)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:210)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:170)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:194)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.firstOrNull(_Sequences.kt:168)
    at com.android.tools.idea.testartifacts.instrumented.testsuite.actions.ImportUtpResultActionKt.findFileByRelativePathToContentRoot(ImportUtpResultAction.kt:270)
    at com.android.tools.idea.testartifacts.instrumented.testsuite.actions.ImportUtpResultActionKt.getDefaultAndroidGradlePluginTestDirectory(ImportUtpResultAction.kt:255)
    at com.android.tools.idea.testartifacts.instrumented.testsuite.actions.ImportUtpResultActionKt.createImportUtpResultActionFromAndroidGradlePluginOutput(ImportUtpResultAction.kt:180)
    at com.android.tools.idea.testartifacts.instrumented.testsuite.actions.ImportTestGroup$getUtpTestHistoryActions$1.invokeSuspend(ImportTestGroup.kt:77)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequenceBuilderIterator.hasNext(SequenceBuilder.kt:129)
    at com.android.tools.idea.testartifacts.instrumented.testsuite.actions.ImportTestGroup.getChildren(ImportTestGroup.kt:91)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.doGetChildren(ActionUpdater.java:647)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.lambda$new$1(ActionUpdater.java:113)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.lambda$callAction$9(ActionUpdater.java:200)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$0(ProgressManager.java:57)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:188)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:624)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:646)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:623)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:175)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.runProcess(ProgressManager.java:57)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.lambda$callAction$10(ActionUpdater.java:198)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdateEdtExecutor.lambda$computeOnEdt$0(ActionUpdateEdtExecutor.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.lambda$expandActionGroupFastTrack$3(Utils.java:256)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.runLoopAndWaitForFuture(Utils.java:582)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.expandActionGroupFastTrack(Utils.java:254)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.expandActionGroupImpl(Utils.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.fillMenu(Utils.java:278)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenu.fillMenuInner(ActionMenu.java:362)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.performWithRetries(Utils.java:620)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenu.fillMenu(ActionMenu.java:341)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenu.setPopupMenuVisible(ActionMenu.java:312)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JPopupMenu.menuSelectionChanged(JPopupMenu.java:1484)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager.setSelectedPath(MenuSelectionManager.java:129)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI$Handler.mouseEntered(BasicMenuUI.java:584)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6663)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEnterExit(Container.java:4698)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Container.java:4676)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4527)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2790)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:891)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:820)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:757)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:818)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:498)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException: PersistentEnumerator storage corrupted C:\Users\hissain.sk\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.3\caches\names.dat
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.catchCorruption(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:602)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.doEnumerate(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.enumerate(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:279)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumerator.enumerate(PersistentEnumerator.java:123)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentStringEnumerator.enumerate(PersistentStringEnumerator.java:70)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.lambda$getNameId$22(FSRecords.java:509)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.readAndHandleErrors(FSRecords.java:248)
    ... 96 more'
```